# How to make sure random.choice doesn't select the same items twice?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
categories = {
    "fruits" = ['banana', 'apple', 'strawberry', 'grape', 'watermelon', 'mango'],
    "countries" = ['Canada', 'Brazil', 'Ghana', 'Cuba', 'Japan', 'Germany', 'France'],
    "colors" = ['green', 'brown', 'pink', 'yellow', 'red', 'grey', 'blue']
    }
```

And I need a function that returns a category/key (like 'colors') and 3 different words from one single key/category (like 'brown', 'pink', 'yellow'). So I wrote:

```
category = random.choice(list(categories))
print(category)
words = random.choice(categories[category]), random.choice(categories[category]), random.choice(categories[category])
print(words)
```

But sometimes it returns the same words. For example:

```
colors
('brown', 'blue', 'blue')
```

What can I do to make sure it will always return me 3 different words?

Comment: Try to explore `random.sample()`?

Comment: Repeatedly calling `random.choice()` is not the right thing to do - each call is unaware of the previous ones. You have `random.choices()` if you want repetitions, and `random.sample()` if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Put the second block of code inside a loop and then add the following statement at the end of the loop

```
if colors==set(colors):
   break
```